# making url rewrites dynamic

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is an example of my url rewrites.

```
# Redirect /page1.php?parameter-view=value to /page1/value
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+page1\.php\?parameter-view=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page1/%1? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /page1/value to /page1.php?parameter-view=value
RewriteRule ^page1/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /page1.php?parameter-view=$1&parameter-id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# Internally forward /page1/value to /page1.php?parameter-view=value
RewriteRule ^page1/(.*)?$ /page1.php?parameter-view=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Redirect /page2.php?parameter-view=value to /page2/value
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+page2\.php\?parameter-view=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page2/%1? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /page2/value to /page2.php?parameter-view=value
RewriteRule ^page2/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /page2.php?parameter-view=$1&parameter-id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# Internally forward /page2/value to /page2.php?parameter-view=value
RewriteRule ^page2/(.*)?$ /page2.php?parameter-view=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I have a set of rewrites for page1 and page2. Is there a way to combine these rewrites so everytime I make a new page I can just add the page "page3" instead of adding a 3rd group of rewrites? Example of what I'm going for:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(page1|page2|page3)\.php\?parameter-view=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /(page1|page2|page3)/%1? [R=302,L]


RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /(page1|page2|page3).php?parameter-view=$1&parameter-id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3)/(.*)?$ /(page1|page2|page3).php?parameter-view=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

The best case scenario is i refine not only the idea of using the same rewrite for all pages but maybe not even having to use 3 to do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure you can do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(page1|page2|page3)\.php\?parameter-view=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /$1.php?parameter-view=$2&parameter-id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3)/(.*)/?$ /$1.php?parameter-view=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This is what I needed! Tried editing but not enough characters to edit.

1 Problem: You have parameter-view=$1 and not $3 in this scenario.

Comment: Ah sorry, it is fixed now.